# Access Reverse Relation in django

Tags: python, django

Models.py

```
class MaterialRequest(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allotment_sales')
    flow = models.ForeignKey(Flow, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='flow')
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kit')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_allocated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class AllotmentDocket(models.Model):

    transaction_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    dispatch_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(MaterialRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allotment_sales')
    parent_company = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allotment_parent')

    plastic_pallet = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    side_wall = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    top_lid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    insert = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    separator_sheet = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I wan to access all the material request as well as the ones which have allotment docket to create a table.
For e.g I have 5 Material Request and 3 Allotment dockets, i want a table in which there are 5 rows showing all the details of material request's objects and the respective allotment objects

Something like this:

```
owner flow kit quantity platic_pallet side_wall top_lid Insert 
 1     1    1     1        1              1        1      1  
 2     2    2     2        2              2        2      2
 3     3    3     3        3              3        3      3 
 4     4    4     4        -              -        -      - 
 5     5    5     5        -              -        -      -
```

Views.py

```
def mat_details(request):
    value = request.POST['my-select']
    start = request.POST['from']
    end = request.POST['to']

    client_pk = Client.objects.filter(client_name = value)[0]

    mat_req = MaterialRequest.objects.filter(owner = client_pk.pk, created_on__range =[start, end] )

    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/matdeatils.html', {'query': mat_req})
```

Comment: Show your view and template so far.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated the question with views, I have not created the template as of now because I am not able to understand how to get the Allotment objects related with material request

Answer (score 3):

Your two tables have a one-to-many relationship, meaning that a `MaterialRequest` entry can have multiple corresponding `AllotmentDocket` entries.

Because you added a `related_name` to the `ForeignKey` to `MaterialRequest`, every `MaterialRequest` object will have a property named `allotment_sales` that is a way of retrieving and manipulating all the `AllotmentDocket` objects related to the current `MaterialRequest`.

Try doing the following in the Django shell:

```
>>> material_request = MaterialRequest.objects.first()
>>> material_request.allotment_sales.count()
>>> material_request.allotment_sales.all()
>>> material_request.allotment_sales.first()
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Regarding the table you are trying to display, if every row is a `MaterialRequest` record, how should the columns from `AllotmentDocket` be computed? Are they aggregates, e.g. `platic_pallet` is the sum/average of all `platic_pallet` values of the allotment dockets of a material request?

If you're considering a table display, maybe you should have each row represent a `AllotmentDocket` object, i.e. the "many" part in the one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

As Iulia said in other answer, the relation between `MaterialRequest` and `AllotmentDocket` is ForeignKey, means one `MaterialRequest` can have multiple `AllotmentDocket`. If that happens, then you can use [**`Sum`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) to sum up the values of `platic_pallet`, `side_wall,` `top_lid`, `insert` from reverse relation in a single query using [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/). For example:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

client_pk = Client.objects.filter(client_name = value)[0]
mat_req = MaterialRequest.objects.filter(
    owner=client_pk.pk,
    created_on__range=[start, end]
).annotate(
    plastic_pallet=Sum('allotment_parent__plastic_pallet')
).annotate(
    side_wall=Sum('allotment_parent__side_wall')
).annotate(
    top_lid=Sum('allotment_parent__top_lid')
).annotate(
    insert=Sum('allotment_parent__insert')
)
```

And use it in template:

```
{% for i in query %}
    {{ i.plastic_pallet }}
    {{ i.side_wall }}
    {{ i.top_lid }}
    {{ i.insert }}
{% endfor %}
```

*By the way(or maybe unrelated)*, if there is [**`OneToOne`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation between `MaterialRequest` and `AllotmentDocket`, then you can simply use `{{ i.allotment_parent.side_wall }}` in template to get `side_wall` information.